# Is there a way to force TinyMCE to create <div> tables instead of using <table> tags when using the table button?

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-table, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using the TinyMCE HTML editor on my site; however, I see that TinyMCE uses `<table>` tags when I use the table button is there a way that I can force TinyMCE to use `<div>` tags for tables this way my content will remain responsive?

Comment: In what way are divs more responsive than tables?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, this is not possible out of the box.
The only way to get what you want is to write a table plugin yourself (and that would be painful).

Answer (score 0):

```
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('BeforeSetContent', function(e) {
        if (e.content.startsWith("<table ")) {
            // write jquery code to replace <table> tag with a <div> tag whenever a table is added in the editor.
        }
    });
},
```

May some filter function like this:

```
$('table').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'Text Here';
}).replaceWith(function () {
    return '<div>' + $(this).text() + '</div>';
})
```